# Resultset is never closed - Sonarqube analysis

Tags: java, sonarqube, resultset

In our code , we have closed the results sets in finally block still the sonar shows that it is never closed. Kindly help.Here we have created connection using Spring datasource utils and using the same have released the connections to pool.

```
try {
  con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource); // connection to database using spring
  stmt = con.createStatement();
  rs = stmt.executeQuery("<>");
  .
  .
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
finally {
  if (stmt != null && !stmt.isClosed()) {
    stmt.close();
  }
  if (rs != null && !rs.isClosed()) {
    rs.close();
  }
  if (con != null) {
    DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, dataSource);
  }
}
```

Comment: Given the construct you have shown, you could convert to using a `try with resources` approach, then you could get rid of the finally block (well, mostly).

Comment: Don't trust SonarQube; it's frequently wrong-headed and sometimes just plain wrong.

Comment: Thanks Kevin...! As of now i cant use that option ...! i have found the solution and have given it below!!! it was really hard to crack what Sonar thinks

Comment: @DavidW - Yea .. kind of .. keeps telling me to do some silly things which really i feel is not necessary .....

Answer (score 3):

It's possible for

```
stmt.close();
```

to throw a SQLException.  If that happens then

```
rs.close();
```

will never be executed. As others have suggested, consider using `try with resource`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the try-with-resource statement to cleanup your code and ensure proper resource handling:

```
try (final Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource); // connection to database using spring
    final Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("<>");) {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
   // handle Exceptions here
}
```

Comment: Thanks DPR.. That was right option.. But client not ready to change it as it might involve slightly bigger testing scope.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason why Sonar is throwing the error even though we have closed the resources.

the Sonar expects each resource to be closed separately in separate try catch. The reason behind sis if once resource closure causes issue, others might be left open too.

Like this,

```
finally{
try{
if(resultset!=null){
resultset.close();
}
catch(SQLException e){
---
---
}
if(connection!=null){
connection.close();
}
catch(SQLException e){
---
---
}
}
```

Again in the above code, please add logger.error in exception to avoid another error from Sonar !! !     :) 
`logger.error("", e);`